# Clarifying Berger et al. "A Maximum Entropy Approach to NLP"

Tags: natural-language, notation, maximum-entropy

Unfortunately, I do not know where else to turn to for clarifications that I require regarding the notations and definitions in the initial sections of the paper by Berger et al (1996).

In Section 3.2, they say, "To express the event that *in* translates as *en* when *April* is the following word, we can introduce the indicator function

$f(x,y) \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\, 1$ if $y = $ *en* and *April* follows *in*;

$f(x,y) \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\, 0$ otherwise.
"

Immediately afterwards, they start discussing the expected value of $f$. I don't get it. Isn't $f$ an indicator function? Why should we treat it like a random variable? I don't see any "randomness" in the values that $f$ returns (cf. definition above). Is there an intuition behind this random variable $f$ and its expected value?

I feel that this is crucial to understanding the rest of the paper and would appreciate any help. Perhaps this has to do with my unfamiliarity with the general writing style in this field.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You might consider renaming this question to something like "Clarifying the application of indicator functions to random variables in NLP models"?

Answer (score 2):

The function of a random variable is a random variable itself (If $X$ is a random variable, $f(X)$ is also a random variable, so you can define the expected value of it). In your example, since the occurrence of words in a text can be regarded as random variables, the defined $f(x,y)$ is also a random variable.

Also note that if $f(X)$ is an indicator function, i.e., $f(X)=1$ if $X=x_0$ and $f(X)=0$ otherwise, its expected value is equal to $P(X=x_0)$. So in your example, the expected value of $f$ is equal to `P(y=en and April follows in)`.

Comment: What you say makes sense. As per their definitions (and although it is not clearly stated) when referring to $f(x,y)$ they imply $y = $ _en_ and $x = $ _April_ follows _in_. But this is just one instance of the random variable $(X,Y)$ where $X$ is the set containing "all possible neighbors of _in_" and $Y$ contains "all possible French translations of _in_." 

Their formula for the expected value of $f$ is $\Sigma_{(x,y)} p(x,y) f(x,y)$, where $p(x,y)$ is the empirically determined probability of seeing the pair $(x,y)$. 

Would this change your explanation?

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. $f(x,y) = 0$ whenever $y \neq $ _en_ or $x \neq $ _April_ follows _in_. So the expected value of $f$ as given by their formula is indeed $p(x,y)$. But then, they ought to be defining an indicator variable for every possible pair $(x,y)$.

Comment: Without looking at the paper, but: It's quite normal for NLP classifiers to generate thousands or, more likely, even millions of indicator functions for every possible combination of "events" (here: words/n-grams) you are interested in. So they probably have functions for very many possible pairs, very probably for (nearly - you might filter low frequency cases) all pairs they find in the corpus the model is trained on.

Comment: But then, analyzing the feature in terms of expectation seems superfluous. The way it is defined, the expectation is always going to be the empirically computed probability of observing the pair (or feature) in the training corpus. Then why talk about expectation at all?